# How do I configure an unattended (via CI) brew installation on macOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have a new Mac that has just run the git installation. I'd like to have a process I can invoke via CI (aka Jenkins) that will install brew unattended. Ideally, said process would only utilize native tools installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

All files are expected to be in same directory.

file 1, saved as `askpass.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
```

file 2, saved as `install_brew.sh`:

```
if [ -z ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD+x} ]; then
    echo "KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD is unset in calling environment, required to install brew"
    exit 1
fi
set -e
# brew will run some sudo commands, this gives it permission to do so
echo $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD | sudo -S 'ls'
chmod 700 askpass.sh
export SUDO_ASKPASS=$(pwd)/askpass.sh
# unattended installation mode for brew
CI=1 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
ls -l /usr/local/bin/brew # ensure this worked or generate nonzero exit code
```

Invocation:
Ensure `KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD` is set in the calling environment, then
`sh install_brew.sh`

Comment: This probably won't work for Catalina because ruby is no longer part of the system? I don't recall.